# Could i substitute regular expressions listed in an input mapping file to modify a input csv using perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to replace few regular expressions listed in map file with the regular expression listed in same map file separated by ":" or some other delimiter.

I want to make all these substitution in a input csv file and produce an output file with all these substitutions.
So, i have 2 inputs and 1 output file.
For e.g.

> 1.) Mapping File content e.g.
>   GMAC(\d+)_RMII_REF_CLK_O:GMAC$1_RMII_REF_CLKO
>   GMAC(\d+)_RMII_REF_CLK_I:GMAC$1_RMII_REF_CLKI 
>   SPI[(\d+)]:SPI$1
>   ,SPI(\d+),:,SPI$1_SPI$1, 
>   ,LIN(\d+),:,UART_$1_UART$1,
>   LIN(\d+)_TX:TXD
>
> 2.) Input content file 
>   ,GMAC0_RMII_REF_CLK_O,GMAC_0,,O, 
>   ,GMAC0_RMII_REF_CLK_I,GMAC_0,,I, 
>   ,GMAC1_RMII_REF_CLK_O,GMAC_1,,O,
>   ,GMAC1_RMII_REF_CLK_I,GMAC_1,,I, 
>   ,DSPI2_SOUT,DSPI_2,,O,
>   ,LIN1_TX,LINFlex_1,,O,
>
> 3.) My output file should have content like this 
>   ,GMAC0_RMII_REF_CLKO,GMAC_0,,O, ,GMAC0_RMII_REF_CLKI,GMAC_0,,I,
>   ,GMAC1_RMII_REF_CLKO,GMAC_1,,O, ,GMAC1_RMII_REF_CLKI,GMAC_1,,I,
>   ,SPI2_SOUT,SPI2_SPI2,,O,
>   ,TXD,UART_1_UART1,,O,

I don't want to hardcoded my script for all similar substitutions.
The regular expressions in mapping file could be defined by user.

I am trying below code which is not working:

```
            my $io_data = read_file($IO_Signal_Table);
            my $in_data = read_file($Input_Muxing);

            open(MAP_FILE,"$map_file") || die "Can't open $map_file for reading $!";

            while (my $line = <MAP_FILE>) {
            chomp($line);

            my @content = split(":",$line);
            my $content0 = qr/$content[0]/;
            my $content1 = qr/$content[1]/;
            # print "\n $content0 $content1 ";

            $io_data =~ s/$content0/$content1/g; 
            $in_data =~ s/$content0/$content1/g; 

            # $io_data =~ s/$content[0]/$content[1]/g; 
            # $in_data =~ s/$content[0]/$content[1]/g; 
            }


            close(MAP_FILE);

            write_file($IO_Signal_Table_mod,$io_data);
            write_file($Input_Muxing_mod,$in_data);
```

P.S: 
    I am using perl. I could see all this done in script but didn't find an example where it reads substitution regex from a file as needed for me.
    I am basically avoiding the gvim command script for substitution using perl.
    I am using perl on redhat linux  v5.12.2.

Comment: The formatting of your file examples seems messed up.

Comment: How? could you please elaborate?

Comment: All pattern pairs were on one logical line in the post, while your code works with one pair per line; but you have edited it meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying below code which is not working:
>
> ```
>             my $content0 = qr/$content[0]/;
>             my $content1 = qr/$content[1]/;
>             …
>             $io_data =~ s/$content0/$content1/g;
> ```

Do not quote the *replacement* part of the substitution as a regular expression. Reason: The `qr` operator returns a normalized version of the string, of the form `(?-xism:…)`, and this is inept as a replacement. Just use `my $content1 = $content[1];`.